# How to handle Dropwizard metrics if the service goes down or is restarted?

Tags: dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I have a use case where we have to monitor the various stats of service where we are using Dropwizard metrics and pushing them to a server. But the metrics are reset if the service goes down and is restarted. The counters are reset to 0 which will affect monitoring since the values like percentiles or averages are affected.

How to deal with such a situation or use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a data aggregator like Graphite or something similar. You would periodically post the metrics to Graphite. Dropwizard has a plug in for that https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/graphite/

Comment: I tried a hell lot of reporters with this... Learnt many things... Thanx for the solution...

Comment: @SantoshTulasiram can you share what reporter you have finalized?

Comment: we came up with our own reporter, where we push the data to elastic search cluster and use kibana for graphs and alert on top of that.

Comment: @SantoshTulasiram Could you please elaborate the alert part of your solution.

Comment: https://github.com/dhatim/dropwizard-metrics-elasticsearch. Use this one to emit the metrics to elasticsearch.